# Docker OSX - Unable to access container on port 8080

Tags: wordpress, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm using `docker-machine` along with `docker` on OSX El Capitan. I am attempting to run the Wordpress docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like so:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80

db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secretpassword
```

And I launch it with: `docker-compose run wordpress`. Everything loads fine and the containers can be seen running with `docker ps`:

```
c7ade4a3944b        wordpress           "/entrypoint.sh apach"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        80/tcp              awesomebingo_wordpress_run_8
30bc8d7aaad6        mariadb             "/docker-entrypoint.s"   51 minutes ago      Up 2 minutes        3306/tcp            awesomebingo_db_1
```

I get the IP address of the VM using:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Which returns:

```
192.168.99.100
```

If I try to access http://192.168.99.100:8080 from the browser I get an error: Unable to connect, in Firefox.

I can not ping the VM IP address in a normal terminal, but if I'm in the Docker Quickstart Terminal I am able to `ping` and `nmap` the VM's IP address. Although `nmap` still shows port `8080` as closed.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using:

```
docker-compose run wordpress
```

I instead needed to use:

```
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

In correct variant `docker ps` should show next in ports column:

```
 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

> Launch your image like **:**

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t wordpress
```